# Access violation in module ilink32.dll

Tags: c++, linker, c++builder

I have a gigantic C++ Builder 6 solution, when I try to compile it I get the following error when the linker starts its work:

[image: Error in german]

It translates to:

```
---------------------------
Fehler
---------------------------
Access violation at address 0660EE22 in module 'ilink32.dll'. Reading from address 00000000.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Does anyone have an idea how this comes and how I can fix it?

### EDIT 1

Important note, the code sometimes compiles, mostly then, when I reset the working copy and then just modify the stuff in sublime text and use C++ Builder only for compiling. Including, I don't open a single file.

### EDIT 2

Some more details, the project has about 80.000.000 lines of code (according to C++ Builder). The largest file is about 70.000 lines, but you cannot say clearly, because there are a lot of

```
#ifdef XY
#endif
```

Things.

The code itself is copy-paste from an existing part and got reviewed by some coworkers. So I think it is a bug in C++ Builder, because it actually works if I just use Sublime Text or Notepad++ to edit the stuff and then use C++ Builder to build it, it works (at least sometimes).

To be honest, I myself don't think there is a real solution. But I hope someone knows this bug. According to Google, the `ilink32.dll` is a C++ Builder library that is linked automatically.

Maybe someone has a solution.

Comment: So it's your program crashes or C++ Builder?

Comment: @Drop I get this message on linking. So I would say C++ Builder.

Comment: Well, the easiest solution is to stop using obsolete tools. On Windows you could try [Visual Studio 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/), it's free. It ships with modern C++11/C++14 compiler, and it never crashes. Well, almost never ;)

Comment: @Drop, I know, I personally use Visual Studio, just the company I work for doesn't and the project is also not compatible with Visual Studio... So I need to use this -_-

Comment: My first suspicion is that Builder is running out of memory. Have you, or somebody else, successfully built this project before?

Comment: @molbdnilo Just 50 minutes ago :/ I made a change and that caused the problem. The virtual machine I am working in has 4GB memory, I think that should be enough. It is the main application in the company, and we build it every day multiple times...

Comment: @Knerd than it would be logical to share this "change" with us. We are programmers, show us the code!

Comment: @Drop, if I could I would, you might see in my profile, I am here longer, but this code is relativly secret and it sometimes compiles. My guess is, the file is way to long. I made an edit :)

Comment: @Knerd Great secret written in Borland C++? Than we could barely help you. Try to read your post, there is 0.0% of technical information useful to resolve a problem. This way, you'll either need to find a dinosaur programmer which still can enumerate all the Borland C++ bugs along with solutions or an psycho-telekinetic-coder which can solve any issues remotely by connecting to your virtual machine directly with a mind-link. If you are "longer" on SO, you should know that you can't expect normal people to deduce a problem by "Access violation in 'ilink32.dll'" kind of descriptions.

Comment: @Drop I edited the question a lot, I hope it helps...

Comment: @Drop if you don't have any ideas you don't need to post, and you can wait for those "dinosaur borland c++" programmers to notice the tags

Comment: check any existing tickets, http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?search=1&proj=15&kw=ilink32&plat=900, or http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=15154

Comment: @MattMcNabb if you post it as an answer, I can accept it. I think that is the best I will get and on monday I try if it works :)

Comment: I have some other ideas too, will make a post later

Comment: @MattMcNabb thanks, you might save my nerves and time :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb How are the chances? :) I am at work again and really could need the help :)

Answer (score 1):

The ilink32 has always had a lot of bugs. There's no chance of getting anything fixed in non-current versions , so your options are:

- Look for workarounds on QC
- Find your own workaround

[Here](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?search=1&proj=15&kw=ilink32&plat=900) [are](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=15154) some QC searches that may or may not be useful to you.

AFAIK it is not possible to use a different linker. However you can turn on (or turn off) Incremental Linking via the project options and see if that makes a difference. Incremental linking is a speed optimization, it makes no difference to the semantics of linking.

> the project has about 80.000.000 lines of code (according to C++ Builder).

Well, that number counts all lines in precompiled headers for each source file so maybe it doesn't mean much.

70K LOC is large for one source file; perhaps you could try refactoring code to have smaller object files, especially if it does seem that adding to a big file does trigger the problem.

It might be possible to identify which change you are making that is triggering the bug. For example it might be increasing a particular thing past some limit (e.g. size of one object file  , number of object files, size of static data, etc.)

You could delete the precompiled header files (that is vclNN.csm, vclNN.#00, vclNN.#01, etc.) that are built and saved by default in the BCB6 lib directory. Perhaps they got corrupted or could be rebuilt better. PCH management is difficult in BCB6 anyway. (I ended up defining my own "all.h" and having every source file do `#include "all.h"` `#pragma hdrstop`). Later versions of CBB XE allow PCH injection making this process a lot tidier.

Have a look at the actual link command being passed to ilink32 and see if there are any unnecessary object files or libraries in it.  You could delete and re-create the project files as they can build up crud over time as a project is developed. Actually that is probably a good idea anyway.

Another possibility might be to group some of the code into static libraries .

**In all cases make sure you are using good source control so you can reverse out any failed options that might make things worse**

Comment: Thank you :) by now it worked when I reverted the changes in the project file in svn and then rebuild all. That works usually. The problem is, that we are not allowed to reactor the code. Otherwise the large files would be way smaller by now :/ I gonna try your ideas tomorrow :)